# word frequency program in python

Tags: python, dictionary, word-frequency

Say I have a list of words called words i.e. words = ["hello", "test", "string", "people", "hello", "hello"] and I want to create a dictionary in order to get word frequency.

Let's say the dictionary is called 'counts'

```
counts = {}
for w in words:
    counts[w] = counts.get(w,0) + 1
```

The only part of this I don't really understand is the counts.get(w.0).  The book says, normally you would use counts[w] = counts[w] + 1 but the first time you encounter a new word, it won't be in counts and so it would return a runtime error.  That all fine and dandy but what exactly does counts.get(w,0) do?  Specifically, what's the (w,0) notation all about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a dictionary, `get()` is a method where `w` is a variable holding the word you're looking up and `0` is the default value.  If `w` is not present in the dictionary, `get` returns `0`.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, with Python 2.7 and above you may prefer to operate with `collections.Counter`, like:

```
In []: from collections import Counter
In []: c= Counter(["hello", "test", "string", "people", "hello", "hello"])
In []: c
Out[]: Counter({'hello': 3, 'test': 1, 'people': 1, 'string': 1})
```

Answer (score 4):

The dictionary `get()` method allows for a default as the second argument, if the key doesn't exist.  So `counts.get(w,0)` gives you `0` if `w` doesn't exist in `counts`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if there is no key `w` in `counts`, then  `counts.get(w)` will evaluate to `None`.  And the line `counts.get(w) + 1` will be equivalent to `None + 1`, and will throw a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method on a dictionary returns the value stored in a key, or optionally, a default value, specified by the optional second parameter.  In your case, you tell it "Retrieve 0 for the prior count if this key isn't already in the dictionary, then add one to that value and place it in the dictionary."